# Adding SDK-specific frameworks to Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode

Xcode 3.2 kind of broke the build process of my iPhone app. I need to add a new framework to my project (MediaPlayer.framework).

So I go into my Target settings and try to add it to the "Linked Libraris" by hitting the [+] button. In the list the MediaPlayer.framework is missing, as well as other frameworks, such as UIKit, CoreGraphic and others. Some frameworks are still there.

I can add the frameworks by adding the SDK-specific ones (going into /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOs.platform/...yadayadayada../frameworkd/) but then of course I can only compile for the iPhone platform and not for the simulator any more.

So basically I wonder how I can get Xcode back to chose the appropriate framework, depending on platform and SDK version for me?

Thanks and kind regards, Hans Schneider

Edit: Things I tried: Setting the Base SDK to 3.0 (was still 2.2.1), reinstalling 3.0 iPhone and Simulator SDK from the "packages" directory of the Xcode 3.2 DMG. Didn't help. The frameworks still wont show up in the list...

Edit 2: Ok, I  now have the frameworks back in the list, I was previously in my AdHoc configuration. In Debug I have the frameworks back. But it still wont compile for the Simualtor (lots of Symbols(s) not found errors).
Looks like the linker doesn't choose the correct libraries and always uses the iPhoneOs3.0 path for the frameworks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Goto 'Framework Search Path' in build section in target's property.

Add path:

```
$(SDKROOT)/Library/System/Frameworks
```

Then it should work well.

And once you press 'OK', you should be able to see the path is set to '/Library..."

Comment: Thanks a lot, that did it! I actually had to remove the other entries from "Framework Search path" which pointed to the specific frameworks for iPhone OS AND Simulator.